E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian bookworm Release' does not have a Release file. among other errors
When typing the following command,
sudo apt update

I get the following errors and warnings:
Ign:1 http://archive.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bookworm InRelease                                                                                
Hit:3 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                     
Ign:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease                                               
Hit:5 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease          
Ign:6 http://archive.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Err:8 http://archive.debian.org/debian bookworm Release
 404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
Err:9 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security Release
 404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
Err:10 http://archive.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates Release
 404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian bookworm Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19

I tried to modify the mysql.list inside sources.list.d to remove it (another error there, saying W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C.), but now i have all the warnings you see!
mysql.list:
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
# deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bookworm mysql-5.7
#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bookworm mysql-tools-preview
# deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bookworm mysql-5.7


Debian 12 (“Bookworm”) is currently supported and therefore hosted on the main mirror network, not the archive. You need to replace the archive.debian.org entries with deb.debian.org in /etc/apt/sources.list and files under /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

now it says (target packages) are configured multiple times!

Those warnings tell you exactly where the entries are duplicated. Even if you’re not good at this I hope that’s enough to figure out what to do ;-).
